# Replace apt package manager with dnf package manager for Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dnf

Does anyone here know how to get rid of the `apt` package manager and replace it with `dnf`(built from source). Do not ask me why; it's just my preference. Also, in the future, if I wanted to edit what sources `dnf` installs packages from, how do I achieve this? Thanks for your time.

---

If you need further explanation, please ask me a question so that we can be on the same page. Hopefully, my question was straightforward.

Comment: Since the package manager is such an integral part of a Linux distribution, why not switch to a distribution that uses `dnf` by default?  I mean, the packages are basically what makes and defines any specific distribution.

Comment: @Kusalananda I understand. I'll switch to Centos. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian is built around `apt`/`dpkg`. Even if you magically build `dnf` and make it use `dpkg` instead of `rpm` (which is a mammoth task), it still cannot use Debian/apt repositories.

I recommend abandoning this idea and using a dnf/rpm based distro instead. Or, if you love Debian, you could write wrappers for common dnf/rpm commands using apt/dpkg (like I did in the past - can share it with you).

Comment: I personally prefer DNF/RPM to APT/DPKG any day of the week. For instance DNF/RPM will never leave your system in a broken state, while you can trivially do that with DPKG without using any special options.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Also, I am trying to build an `LFS` distro to better understand how Linux works. Is it possible to use `Centos/SElinux` as base templates for my `LFS` distro?

Comment: I'm not sure what "base template" means. Also mind that LFS is built around the most up to date packages while RHEL sticks to quite old packages in order to provide stability and quality.

Comment: Even if you ignore the other complexities, dependency hell, AKA the VERSION problem is an NP-complete problem.

The design decisions made by Debian and Fedora to reduce this to a tractable problem are fundamentally incompatible as they chose conflicting methods to reduce the problem.

It would be easier to start from the source tarballs or to modify Fedora to be more Debian like.  As you haven't stated what you think is _better_ about Debian it is hard to make suggestions.  But the current path you are following will lead you to known unsolvable problems.